# How to display MongoDB UUID binary ID columns in String UUID format in Jetbrain's Datagrip

Tags: database, mongodb, binary, uuid, datagrip

Is there any way I can transform columns like this, directly into readable `String UUID` values inside the data view?

[image]

I would like to search directly for `String UUID`. Is this possible?

Comment: Getting the same thing but with subtype 04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but you need to tell MongoDB driver which UUID format you want to use (Java legacy, C# legacy or Python legacy).

Go to datasource settings > Advanced tab and edit **uuidRepresentation** value.

[image]

Comment: is there way how to preserve this javaLegacy also when exporting data as JSON? It doesn't work (at least in Intellij 2020.3)

Comment: Doesn't work for me to change to javaLegacy. Still seeing `{"$binary": {"base64": "dcTGPqbOTlKiVMeo44SDnQ==", "subType": "04"}}`